# Haw can I handle clicking back button in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I have a screen with really long action. I figured out that I can handle clicking 'Cancel' button by running scheduled task which checks the condition: **context.isCancelling()** during execution of this action. Is there any way to handle clicking 'Back' button during the action execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back button is always disabled while an action is being executed, this cannot be changed programmatically.

If you want to provide a way to cancel an action and to go back to the previous screen, you have to add such a button yourself to the screen. In the action script of the button, you can set an installer variable to `true` and regularly check its value in the action. If the variable is set, call

```
context.goBackInHistory(1);
```

to go back to the previous screen and return from the action.